# Prevent Angular2 from bootstrapping based on URL

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angular, angular2-routing

My angular 2 app is built into an ASP.Net MVC architecture. Due to dated legacy systems I'm using an ASP.Net MVC Controller and view to handle login and cookie based authentication.

However, when I navigate to "~/account/login" the console is flooded with about 350,000 angular errors along the lines of:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

and

> Exception: Error in ./AppComponent class AppComponent_Host - inline template:0:0

and perhaps most telling

> ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: The selector "my-app" did not match any elements

So it's bootstrapping my angular app and looking for the app selector. I don't need the app to boot at the login page since that's legacy junk. Everything is working fine but I hate to flood the console with errors whenever someone goes to log in...

My bootstrapper:

```
import { bootstrap }    from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { HTTP_PROVIDERS } from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { appRouterProviders } from './app.routes';

bootstrap(AppComponent, [
    HTTP_PROVIDERS,
    appRouterProviders

]).catch(err => console.error(err));
```

So my best guess is this can be handled in Global.asax.cs likely in the Application_BeginRequest, though I could be way off...

```
    protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var path = Request.Url.AbsolutePath;

        // To allow access to api via url:
        var isApi = path.StartsWith("/CW/api", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
        // To allow direct access to my account controller:
        var isAccount = path.StartsWith("/CW/account", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
        if (isApi || isAccount)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(Context.Server.MapPath(path)))
            Context.RewritePath(RootUrl);
    }
```